# Что я сделал не верно?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
     #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int matr2(int (*Y)[5], int n, int m) {

    int max, i, j, k = 0, d;
    max = Y[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (Y[j][i] > max) {
                max = Y[j][i];
                k = i;
            }
    d = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) d += Y[i][k];
    return d;
}

int main() {
    int Y[5][5] = {{1, 1, 1, 7, 5},
                   {7, 6, 8, 9, 10},
                   {7, 4, 9, 7, 2},
                   {8, 6, 1, 4, 2},
                   {2, 2, 7, 6, 3}};
    cout << matr2(Y, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: Перепутали m и n местами?

Comment: @andreymal так матрица же квадратная

Comment: @andreymal что Вы имеете ввиду, можете подробнее?

Comment: Неправильно задал вопрос.

Comment: @Эникейщик где ? я Вас не понял?

Comment: @Janbyr я имею в виду, что написанная вами функция отличается от функции, написанной в задании

Comment: в какой строке @andreymal? отличие

Comment: @Janbyr Вы делаете сумму по столбцу, а нужно по строке. Запутались в индексах

Comment: @ Artyomka так что ли нужно for (i = 0; i < n; i++) d += Y[k][j];

Comment: @Janbyr у Вас даже на примере идет сначала i, а после j. Аналогично с k и i

Comment: @Janbyr в противном случае, Вы проходили сначала столбцы, а потом уже строки

Comment: @Janbyr вот прямо здесь. Откуда знать, что неверно, если неизвестно, как должно быть верно

Comment: @Эникейщик ты прав, я только учусь решать задачи разбираюсь в азах с++

Comment: При чем ту "азы с++"? Сейчас вопрос выглядит как "я варил суп, он не получился. Что я сделал не так"

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы абсолютно правы! учту Ваш совет!!!

Comment: @Эникейщик Значит я неправильно использовал ингридиенты супа

Comment: @Эникейщик Где нужно был сахар положил соль, а где нужен соль положил сахар. Получается как то так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправленный вариант

```
int matr2(int(*Y)[5], int n, int m) 
{
    int max, i, j, k = 0, d;
    max = Y[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (Y[i][j] > max) // Тут перепутали местами индексы
            { 
                max = Y[i][j]; // тут
                k = i;
            }
    d = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) d += Y[k][i]; // И тут
    return d;
}
```

Comment: ответ все равно не верный выходит

Comment: @Janbyr, судя по той фотографии, которую Вы дали в качестве "вопроса", ответ должен быть 40, либо уточните детали вопроса, что должна делать Ваша программа, и каков итоговый результат

Comment: Спасибо! Я уточну детали вопроса и отпишу в комментарий

Comment: Все верно там два типа задач один по столбцу другой по строке.